# How can I see the queries that are executed when an object is saved?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can I see the queries that are executed when some operations are made on an object? While working with transactions in hybris, I've found this website: https://blog.expert-soft.com/ecommerce/use-transactions-in-hybris-if-you-care-about-performance/, and I wanted to know how can I enable query logging on my server so that I can see the logs like the ones on the aforementioned website. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Let's have a look of this thread:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12763297/how-can-i-print-the-flexible-search-query-along-wi.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, refer the same link. Option form HAC to enabled DB logs and traces also if need.

Go to HAC-> Monitoring -> Database -> JDBC Logging. Once you enable in the log file it will log the query details with params.. But make sure that you disable as most of the queries printed your logs size may become huge.